# Python - How to convert for loop to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have been trying for a few days now to change this into a numpy array. This is being used to make a transparent image and putting it on the current frame.

Here is the code as a for loop:

```
    alpha_frame = frame[:,:,3] / 255.0
    alpha_foreground = foreground[:,:,3] / 255.0

    for color in range(0, 3):
            frame[:,:,color] = alpha_foreground * foreground[:,:,color] + \
                alpha_frame * frame[:,:,color] * (1 - alpha_foreground)
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
    alpha_frame = frame[:,:,3] / 255.0
    alpha_foreground = foreground[:,:,3] / 255.0

    color = np.arange(0,3)
    frame[:,:,color] = alpha_foreground * foreground[:,:,color] + \
    alpha_frame * frame[:,:,color] * (1 - alpha_foreground)
    return frame
```

Here is the error:

```
frame = alpha_foreground * foreground + \ 
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (480,640) (480,640,4)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error or is the end result not what you desire?

Comment: is `frame` 3d, and the alphas scalars?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, the frame is a 2d image, the frame is from the webcam then I am putting a image on top of it, this code is to make the alpha actually work as opencv doesn't allow transparent images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first, if what you are looking for is a performance gain, instead of

```
alpha_frame = frame[:,:,3] / 255.0
alpha_foreground = foreground[:,:,3] / 255.0

for color in range(0, 3):
        frame[:,:,color] = alpha_foreground * foreground[:,:,color] + \
            alpha_frame * frame[:,:,color] * (1 - alpha_foreground)
```

I would recommend

```
alpha_foreground = foreground[:,:,3] / 255.0
alpha_frame = (1 - alpha_foreground) * (frame[:,:,3] / 255.0)


for color in range(0, 3):
        frame[:,:,color] = alpha_foreground * foreground[:,:,color] + \
            alpha_frame * frame[:,:,color]
```

Which saves a element-wise multiplication in the loop.
And then, if you want to avoid the loop, it'd try:

```
alpha_foreground = np.zeros((4, foreground.shape[0], foreground.shape[1]))
alpha_foreground[:, :, :] = foreground[:,:,3] / 255.0
alpha_foreground = alpha_foreground.transpose((1, 2, 0))

alpha_frame = np.zeros((4, frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1]))
alpha_frame[:, :, :] = frame[:,:,3] / 255.0
alpha_frame = alpha_frame.transpose((1, 2, 0)) * (1 - alpha_foreground)

frame = alpha_foreground * foreground + alpha_frame * frame
```

The numpy broadcasting rules makes it so that if you want to broadcast a 2D array in a 3D array, the dimensions that should match are the last two.

This is correct: n*m broadcasted to k*n*m

This is not: n*m broadcasted to n*m*k

Thus, the fastest solution for broadcasting n*m to n*m*k is to create a k*n*m empty array, broadcast the n*m array and transpose the dimensions.

Careful, a simple .transpose() will turn k*n*m into m*n*k, which isn't what we want, so we have to pass a transposition to .transpose()

Comment: Thank you for answering! This is really helpful feedback. I have one problem though, when I tried your code, I got this error, due to the frame and the image being different resolutions, how would I sort this? Again thanks! 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (161,463) (480,640)

Comment: No problem, be sure to flag this as the answer then! For the different dimensions, you need to either pad your image or resize it. Otherwise, you won't be able to do an element-wise operation.

Comment: Hi I just wanted to let you know I managed to solve the issue with cv2.copyMakeBorder, thank you for pointing me in the right direction of padding the image.

Answer (score 1):

what's wrong with

```
frame = alpha_foreground * foreground + 
      alpha_frame * frame * (1 - alpha_foreground)
```

?

Comment: As it is too slow for my purpose so it needs to be in a numpy array instead to speed it up as for my purpose it reduces it by 20 fps and using your method causes this error: 
    frame = alpha_foreground * foreground + \
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (480,640) (480,640,4)

Comment: That's where knowing the arrays shapes is essential. To multiply and add arrays you have to know the shapes.  Have you, in reading any intro numpy material come across the term `broadcasting`?  If not, then you haven't done enough basic reading.